# Понимание работы History API: возврат на предыдущую страницу

Tags: php, html5-history-api, javascript

Пытаюсь понять работу с History API. Вроде бы с основным разобрался. 
Изменяю адрес и title с помощью `window.history.pushState(data, title [, url])`, с этим проблем нет.

Теперь пытаюсь понять, как должен работать "возврат на предыдущую страницу". Сейчас если пользователь нажимает "назад", то адрес меняется, но сама страница никак не изменяется.

Допустим, есть 2 страницы:

> www.example.com/
>
> www.example.com/test

Пользователь изначально заходит на страницу www.example.com/, нажимает на определённую кнопку, которая вызывает подгрузку определённых форм и изменение адреса страницы на 
www.example.com/test. Если пользователь нажимает на кнопку "назад", то адрес меняется на www.example.com/, но сама страница никак не изменяется.

Вопрос: так и должно быть?

Может, я не так понял, но, в моём понимании, должен был произойти возврат к состоянию страницы www.example.com/... Или всё-таки это работает иначе, и надо также отслеживать возврат назад и прописывать весь "обратный ход" на JS?

**UPD**

[[@TheDoctor](/users/31688/thedoctor)](/users/31688/thedoctor),
Тогда не понимаю, где я мог допустить ошибку. Может, не так формулирую. Попытаюсь объяснить более подробно, убрав всё лишнее.

Допустим, на главной странице только 2 div блока c id "div1" и  "div2" соответственно. Изначально div2 скрыт (display:none). div1 отображается и занимает некоторую область. Клик по div1 вызывает отображение блока div2 и изменяет текущий адрес с / на /test (с помощью history.pushState).

Это так работает, если пользователь открыл изначально /, если же пользователь открыл /test, то сервер выдаёт всё те же 2 блока, только div2 уже отображается (display:block) сразу.

Если пользователь открывает страницу /, кликает по div1 (адрес страницы меняется на /test и div2 отображается), затем нажимает "назад", должен ли блок div2 стать невидимым опять?  Сейчас блок невидимым не становится. Просто адрес меняется и всё.

Comment: > затем нажимает "назад", должен ли блок div2 стать невидимым опять?

Нет, не должен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы всего-навсего меняете URL (логический переход), т.е. страница "физически" не меняется, ибо контент подгружается ajax/websocket/иной "транспорт". Необходимо отследить изменение урла на клиенте - роутинг по урлу. Посмотрите, как это [сделано в Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) или [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/#Router). Т.е. получается [SPA подход](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и ссылки. В общем-то проблемы с реализацией особо нет, но просто получается, что надо написать тогда ещё кучу кода для возврата к предыдущему состоянию(после того как пользователь возвращается на предыдущую страницу), что я делать не хотел и не хочу пока что. 

Вздохнул и пошёл по пути наименьшего сопротивления, заменив все pushState на replaceState. Вроде как и не совсем хорошо, но теперь "назад" будет хотя бы более понятным для пользователя, чем просто изменяющиеся url`ы.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже столкнулся сегодня с этим вопросом. Возможно, мое решение в корне неверно.
В моем приложении ajax запрос возвращает массив из новой ссылки и куска html кода

```
data['html'], data['link']
```

Массив этот я кладу в первый параметр

```
history.pushState(data, null, data['link']);
```

Потом добавляю обработчик на переключение истории. Если при возврате на предыдущую страницу информация о предыдущем ajax ответе существует, то заменяю контент, иначе перезагружаю страницу.

```
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e){
        if(e.state != null){
            $('.somewrapper').html(e.state.html);
        }
        else{
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
```